# Hypernym for "to increase" and "to decrease"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, hypernyms

I'm writing a walkthrough for a video game I really enjoy and I came to a point where there is a system that you can change the "power level" of monsters. It goes up and down, 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - ect...

In my guide I wrote:

> **Increase/Decrease** monster power level. I will explain more later in the guide (...)

I want (don't need to) put it into 1 word. It might be really simple and I just need some rest to get my mind functioning. If you could help, That'd be nice!

Comment: What's wrong with "change", and explain the stepwise change later?

Comment: Oh, change... Man, I guess I really do need some rest.

Comment: If in unit steps then *increment* and *decrement* would be descriptive.

Comment: change or alter both mean to make a difference in the state or condition of a thing or system.

Comment: *Change, adjust, customize, alter, specify, adapt, modify...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

[**regulate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regulate) the monster's power?

(M-W): to set or adjust the amount, degree, or rate of (something)

Comment: Welcome to ELU, surf. Yu could improve the quality of your answer by citing an authoritative source.